# How can I use a regular expression to validate a password?

Tags: regex, validation, asp-classic

How can I use a regular expression to validate the characters in a password?  The password must contain at least 1 special character, 1 digit and 1 letter.  It should [not] be more than 8 characters long.

Comment: I trust you meant 'not fewer than 8 characters'; the security in a password shorter than 8 characters is usually close enough to non-existent.

Answer (score 6):

Must you use regular expressions? It seems like the wrong tool for the job.

Instead, I would implement a function that checks for one each of the characters you would like to see, as well as checking the length. The function will be much easier to read than a regular expression that tries to do the same thing.

Comment: Plus, the ideal password is irregular.

Answer (score 1):

The regex:

`^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[@#$%^&+=]).*$`

will match

- at least 1 digit,
- at least 1 letter and
- at least one special char

Special chars are `'@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '+'` and `'='`, the allowed special chars can be changed by changing the third look-ahead group.

**However I can't get it to match a max length using regex, which means that Greg is most likely correct and regex is not the way to go for this**.  The given regex imposes a minimum password length of 3 based on the three matching look-ahead groups.  You could enforce a minimum length as Jonathan suggests in his comment by adding an additional look-ahead group: `(?=.{8.})` for example gives a minimum length of 8.